# Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http-headers

I've been trying to find a solution, but nothing I found so far worked. So I'm trying to do a HTTP request with angular to a weather API, but I keep getting this response:

```
Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Adding this line to my app config

   delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
2. I Have tried multiple version's of angular, all with the same result
3. Adding this to my .htacces

   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
4. Adding the headers with PHP
5. Trying different URL's for GET requests

   (even different API's, same result)
6. Using the jQuery HTTP request instead of Angular's, same result...

**My code**

```
       $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/myapikey/52.370216,4.895168'
        }).
        success(function(response) {
            console.log('succes');  
            console.log(response);
        }).
        error(function(response) {
            console.log('failed');  
            console.log(response);
        });
```

---

None of these solutions seem to work, I've been using Angular before and normally adding `delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];` would resolve the issue

I'm completely lost here, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using jsonp?

Comment: @subzero — He doesn't run forecast.io, so he can't make them send a JSONP response.

Comment: @Quentin https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2#options they do provide support for jsonp

Comment: Hmm, I assumed it wouldn't be supported since their official library doesn't use it … however the warning associated with that reference is not to be taken lightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api.forecast.io` is not granting permission to `mydomain.com`.

Changing the headers being sent in the request won't help. Changing response headers sent by `mydomain.com` won't help.

The [JavaScript library supplied by forecast.io](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2) uses a proxy. You'll need to take [that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076439/19068) too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jsonp:

`$http.jsonp('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/myapikey/52.370216,4.895168' +'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')...`

link: [Make Jsonp Requests With AngularJs](http://jaketrent.com/post/make-jsonp-requests-with-angularjs/)

Comment: This is the superior answer - no server proxy needed.

Answer (score 0):

Jorge had the right idea.  $http.jasonp is the simplest route.

Here is an example using $q to return a deferred promise.

```
function getForecast( lat, lon ){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var apiKey = 'my-actual-api-key-here';
    var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + lat + ',' + lon + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

    $http.jsonp( url )
        .success( function forecastReceived( forecastData, status, headers, config ) {
            deferred.resolve( forecastData );
        } )
        .error( function forecastFailed( errorData, status, headers, config ) {
            deferred.reject( errorData );
        } );

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

or you can use (as I did) restangular, but you need to set it up first :

```
function isDataGood( forecastData ){
    var isGood = false;
    // test data here 
    // isGood = true;
    return isGood;
}

var apiKey = 'my-actual-api-key-here';
Restangular.setBaseUrl( 'https://api.forecast.io/' );
Restangular.setJsonp( true );
Restangular.setDefaultRequestParams( 'jsonp', { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' } );
var API = Restangular.one( 'forecast/' + apiKey );

function getForecast( lat, lon ){
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   function failed( error ){
       // TODO : retry logic here
       deferred.reject( error );
   }

   API
       .one( lat + ',' + lon )
       .get()
       .then(
           function forecastReceived( forecastData ) {
               if( isDataGood( forecastData ) ){
                   deferred.resolve( forecastData );
               } else {
                   failed( { msg : 'ERROR : received bad data' } );
               }
           },
           function forecastFailed( error ) {
               failed( error );
           } );

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: NOTE : a lot of people have 'RestangularProvider' rather than just 'Restangular' - but it amounts to the same thing.